# Time taken by creating objects with JSON values in AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I have this sentence in the Main.as file:

```
myTweet = new Tweet(jsonArray[servicioElegido].url_json);
trace(myTweet.lastTweet);
```

This sentence pass an String to the contrusctor which is an URL to a JSON, as showed bellow:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

    public class Tweet {
        public var urlMyTweet:String; //URL ak servicio de los Tweets
        public var numFollowers:int; //Num de seguidores
        public var numFollowed:int; //Num de seguidos
        public var numTweets:int; //Num total de Tweets
        public var lastTweet:String; //Ultimo tweet. Texto
        public var lastTweetRet:int; //Retweets del último tweet
        public var lastTweetFav:int; //Favs del último tweet
        public var lastTweetFecha:String;//Fecha del último tweet

        public function Tweet(_urlTweet:String) {
            this.urlMyTweet = _urlTweet;
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            request.url = this.urlMyTweet;
            loader.load(request);
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderCompleteTw);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,informadorIO_Tw);
        }

        private function onLoaderCompleteTw(e:Event):void{
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
            var jsonArray:Array = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(loader.data);
            this.numFollowers = jsonArray[0].user.followers_count;
            this.numFollowed = jsonArray[0].user.friends_count;
            this.numTweets = jsonArray[0].user.statuses_count;
            this.lastTweet = jsonArray[0].text;
            this.lastTweetRet = jsonArray[0].retweet_count;
            this.lastTweetFav = jsonArray[0].favorite_count;
            this.lastTweetFecha = jsonArray[0].created_at;
            trace(this.numFollowers);
            }

        //Para gestionar los errores de IO
        public function informadorIO_Tw(e:Event):void{
            trace(e);
        }

    }

}
```

The problem I have is I really don't know what exactly to do when the Main.as file accesses to any property of the Tweet class to not obtain any 0 in trace sentence.

I think the problem it's regarded to the time taken by the Constructor to ask for the JSON (passed as an String parameter), its not created when the Main.as file ask for any property of the object.

Any ideas?

Comment: loading in AS3 is asynchronous so of course there's nothing to show when you just started to load your json. You do know it very well since you are adding the event listeners yourself (Event.COMPLETE) Only after that event fires you can access your json so just wait for it. Turn it into an EventDispatcher and redispatch the Event.COMPLETE and listen to it.

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed a class that's not very usable.

Your best bet is to tear out the functionality and do the loading of the JSON externally (outside the `Tweet` class).

First of all, the `Tweet` would be only a data object holding a list of properties.

1. Remove everything from the current constructor.
2. Move the content of `onLoaderCompleteTw` into the constructor. Allow for one parameter, which will be the JSON `String`, you pass the value of the parameter to `JSON.decode()`.
3. remove all `URLLoaders` and related code from the class
4. Your `Tweet` class now accepts a JSON response and parses it into its properties.
5. create another class `Twitter` that serves as the connection to the online API, do all the `URLLoader` related things in it, dispatch Events when the JSON is received and parse the information into a `Tweet` object.

A possible usage could look something like this (untested pseudo code):

```
var twitter:Twitter = new Twitter();
twitter.addEventListener(TweetEvent.RECEIVED, onTweet);

function onTweet(e:TweetEvent):void
{
    trace(e.tweet.numTweets);
}
```

---

Twitter is around for a while. It's advisable to use an existing library like [Twitter for As3](https://github.com/susisu/Twitter-for-AS3/blob/master/README_en.md)

Comment: Sounds quite good @null. The solution I wanted to do is a class to handle all the issues for that web service... the rest will be done as you said. So you have any example of that Json handle or any link to investigate in? Thanks.

Comment: @DGM.- instead of doing any of this yourself you should consider using an existing library as the one I linked to. There's not much of an example for the JSON handle I could think of: instead of passing `laoder.data`, you pass the value of the parameter to it. The parameter is of course not an `Event`, but the json response you receive from the `loader`. The real difference is that the `loader` is not part of the class any more.

Comment: So @null I did as you and everything was fine. I managed the communication between my JSON class (with all the connection/errors handled stuff) and my Main/Tweet class and everything was quite well. Thank you guy.